# Blackberry Push notification using C# as server side

Tags: web-services, blackberry

1. I am trying to send push notification in blackberry by using C# Web
   service but i am facing problem is it return exception "The remote
   server returned an error: (404) Not Found.". all info is correct as
   per RIM Standard so please Help me ASAP.

   ```
    [WebMethod]
   public bool push(string notification)
   {
       bool success = true;
       byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello");

       Stream requestStream = null;
       HttpWebResponse HttpWRes = null;
       HttpWebRequest HttpWReq = null;


       String BESName = "cp****.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com";
       try
       {
           //http://<BESName>:<BESPort>/push?DESTINATTION=<PIN/EMAIL>&PORT=<PushPort>&REQUESTURI=/
           // Build the URL to define our connection to the BES.
           string httpURL = "https://" + BESName +  "/push?DESTINATION=2B838E45&PORT=32721&REQUESTURI=/";

           //make the connection
           HttpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(httpURL);
           HttpWReq.Method = ("POST");
           //add the headers nessecary for the push
           HttpWReq.ContentType = "text/plain";
           HttpWReq.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
           // ******* Test this *******
           HttpWReq.Headers.Add("X-Rim-Push-Id", "2B838E45" + "~" + DateTime.Now); //"~" +pushedMessage +
           HttpWReq.Headers.Add("X-Rim-Push-Reliability", "application-preferred");
           HttpWReq.Headers.Add("X-Rim-Push-NotifyURL", ("http://" + BESName + "2B838E45~Hello~" + DateTime.Now).Replace(" ", ""));

           // *************************
           HttpWReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password");

           requestStream = HttpWReq.GetRequestStream();
           //Write the data from the source
           requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

           //get the response
           HttpWRes = (HttpWebResponse)HttpWReq.GetResponse();

           var pushStatus = HttpWRes.Headers["X-RIM-Push-Status"];

           //if the MDS received the push parameters correctly it will either respond with okay or accepted
           if (HttpWRes.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || HttpWRes.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
           {
               success = true;
           }
           else
           {
               success = false;
           }
           //Close the streams

           HttpWRes.Close();
           requestStream.Close();
       }
       catch (System.Exception)
       {
           success = false;
       }

       return success;
   }
   ```

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I tried your code above. Replace

```
String BESName = "cp****.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com";
```

With

```
String BESName = "cpxxx.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_pushRequest";
```

and make sure you provide the right username and password here:

```
HttpWReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

I got success = true;

However, even though the above code executed successfully, I still do not see the push message on the BlackBerry device.